# PHP not sending response text from AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can't work this one out for the life of me, hopefully I am not doing something stupid but why this is not working is not clear to me.

I have a basic HTML page with a JQuery script that sends the following AJAX call to a PHP script within the same directory.

JQuery:

```
// Sends the AJAX request
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "process.php",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
              }
            });
```

PHP:

```
<!-- Ajax request handler -->
<?php 

echo json_encode(array('message' => 'AJAX call received'));

exit();

?>
```

The AJAX call is being made successfully as after debugging it in the console it's status code is 200 and statusText 'ok'. However, I simply cannot get the returned JSON message to show up in the console as it should.

I have double checked the URL and that's fine.

This is the response I get in the console using Jeff Hatz's AJAX Debugger Chrome Extension:

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OejpK.png)

Any ideas folks?

Comment: does a null value or anything get output to console?

Comment: is the php from your process.php file ?

Comment: you could try adding error: function (response) {console.log(response);}

Comment: does the network tab in your console say anything is sent or received?

Comment: What do you see in the console tab? What is the response of the process.php in the network tab?

Comment: have you tried hard refreshing/clearing javascript caches?

Comment: Hit `Ctrl + f5` (works on firefox, dont know if its the same for chrome), to refresh your javascript files. Also sometimes when you are getting a json object, in order to write it wherever, you have to parse it to a String, so `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Also i recommend to set the url like `https://your.page/process.php`

Comment: @Andrew: I have now included a screenshot of what I am getting back in the console using the AJAX Debugger Chrome Extension. Hope that helps.

Comment: Open up the DevTools and go to Network, then click on your PHP file on the left hand side. You should see a "Response" option, if you select that you should get a better outlook on what the file is returning.

Comment: Comment dataType = "json" and try to console log

Comment: @DiabloSteve: I have checked in the network tab and the response of process.php is the JSON message it should be. However it is still not showing up in the console even after trying Francisco Hahn's suggestion of stringifying the response.

Comment: If your PHP is outputting `<!-- Ajax request handler -->` before the json, then the ajax json parser will not work. You must only and truly return a pure json string from your php when using `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: "Not showing up" ? what is the output of  console.log(data);

Comment: Problem solved. I'm an idiot. I had a comment outside of the PHP tags that was obviously causing the problem as @IncredibleHat pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove this line from the top of your PHP:

```
<!-- Ajax request handler -->
```

As when you make a ajax call with `dataType: 'json'` it is not going to parse the response (at all) and then when you do a `console.log(data);` it is simply empty, no console log.

When you do remove that line, you should instead receive in your Network tab Response:

```
{"message":"AJAX call received"}
```

Which then in a `console.log(data);` you should see:

```
Object {message: "AJAX call received"}
```

Comment: Then onward to actually use the `message` value itself, you use normal js objection notation with `data.message`....